# How to call Javascript function in JSF EL conditionally?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have to call JavaScript function based on the bean value. i use the following code

```
onmouseover="#{occasionBean.user.userPreference.defaultPreview==true?'':'Tip()'})"
```

I need to send some parameters in Tip() like this

```
Tip('<img src="pics/image.jpg" width="60">')
```

> Error i am getting is  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: com.sun.faces.el.impl.parser.ParseException: Encountered "test" at line 1, column 60.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       "}" ...
>       "." ...
>       ">" ...
>       "gt" ...
>       "<" ...
>       "lt" ...
>       "==" ...
>       "eq" ...
>       "<=" ...
>       "le" ...
>       ">=" ...
>       "ge" ...
>       "!=" ...
>       "ne" ...
>       "[" ...
>       "+" ...
>       "-" ...
>       "*" ...
>       "/" ...
>       "div" ...
>       "%" ...
>       "mod" ...
>       "and" ...
>       "&&" ...
>       "or" ...
>       "||" ...
>       "?" ...
>       '

Answer (score 2):

First, get rid of the final closing parenthesis:

```
onmouseover="#{occasionBean.user.userPreference.defaultPreview==true?'':'Tip()'}"
```

Then I'd advise against passing HTML constructs as arguments. You'd better use something like:

```
Tip(\'img\', \'pics/image.jpg\', 60)
```

and construct the html in the Tip method, which may be overloaded for different types of tips.

Comment: Hi Bozho I need to send <img> in Tip method then it ll show that image. The Tip() should be called only when defaultPreview== true.

Comment: well, try escaping usign `\'`